# Simple CSS ticker stopped working, help needed with code

Tags: css, webkit

Until recently I had a perfectly working CSS ticker that stopped working for some reason. I am not very proficient with text animation and keyframes inside CSS and I would really appreciate some help. I want to understand what happened and why - and of course how to fix this.

This is supposed to be a simple marquee effect, where the styled text is slowly sliding from right to left to right and it worked flawlessly until it didn't anymore. The text remains styled as I want it to be but there is no more movement.

For example, I would insert a custom HTML block inside Wordpress

```
<span class="sqb__ticker" data-title="&nbsp Speed" aria-hidden="true">Test</span>
```

and style it with this CSS code form my ex developer

```
/* Text ticker BEGIN */
@keyframes ticker {
    from {
        transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
    }
}
.sqb__ticker,
.sqb__ticker::before,
.sqb__ticker::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.sqb__ticker {
    font-size: 90vh;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% + 5vh);
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: max-content;
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-family: "system-ui";
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 3px #3D5A80;
    opacity: 0.09;
}
@media only screen and (max-height: 800px) {
    .sqb__ticker {
        top: 50%;
    }
}
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    .sqb__ticker {
        animation: ticker 120s linear infinite;
    }
}
.sqb__ticker::after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    display: inline-block;
    width: max-content;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .sqb__ticker {
        display: none;
    }
}
/* Text ticker END */
```

This is the Codepen link https://codepen.io/SquareBow-Agency/pen/YzBedzG

The code is exactly the same as it was before when it was working. There were a few WP and theme updates in between but I doubt that is the reason for the CSS to stop working.

I would deeply appreciate your input. Thank you.

I tested this on a couple of different servers and browsers and with older WP core sites and it is still not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: This seems to work in the CodePen provided (changing the animation time reflects in the animation etc). Do you get any console errors/warning (if you open the console, and then refresh the page)?. Also what happens if you inspect the element `.sqb__ticker` in the browser, what CSS do you see for the media query `@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference)`? It could be that your browser _now has_ a preference for `prefers-reduced-motion`, so what  happens if you take the animation _out_ of that media query (and inspect the elements again)?

Comment: Thank you for your input. There were no console errors and CSS was fine. I tested the code in Chrome and Firefox but it was not the browser's fault, either.

I feel really stupid but it turned out to be a Windows 11 setting: all I had to do was to toggle ON Settings > Ease of Access > Display >“Show Animations in Windows. It was the last place I would usually check but it did the trick, everything worked fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This still works but the length of text dictates the speed that needs to be set.

Your example text is very short, so this code below needs updating

```
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    .sqb__ticker {
        animation: ticker 1s linear infinite;
    }
}
```

The value in your data-title attribute needs to match your text, like below.

```
<span class="sqb__ticker" data-title="&nbsp Test" aria-hidden="true">Test</span>
```

Comment: Thank you. It turned out it was not CSS related at all. All I had to do was to toggle ON Settings > Ease of Access > Display >“Show Animations in Windows". It was the last place I would usually check but it did the trick, everything worked fine. It works with any speed setting even if the data-title does not match the text value. Thanks again!